# Android Studio Removing Code Redundancies

Tags: android, android-studio, resharper

I'm trying to ***[remove redundant](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Removing_Code_Redundancies.html)*** that I've in my project.

This option is part of the *ReSharper Tool*, but I didn't found any hint about if this tool is available in Android Studio.

Comment: Sonar is an code analyzing tool that also shows you duplicated code. Might be worth looking for.

Comment: It seems that ReSharper is only for Visual Studio

Comment: yes @WarrenFaith sonar allow only the detection of redundant code, in contrast ReSharper  allow automatic correction of redundant https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Removing_Code_Redundancies.html

Comment: ah ok, didn't know that feature :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. It's already built-in feature in Android Studio regarding to [this post by Andrey Cheptsov](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/07/try-intellij-idea-14-eap-138-1283-4-with-code-cleanup-android-studio-beta-features-and-more/).

Just do this : **Analyse** -> **Code Cleanup** -> ***Specify the scope of the clean***